# CSS vertical-align:middle on div inside anchor

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a div with css property `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` to behave as it "should". My expectation is that text inside these divs would be vertically aligned regardless of whether it's wrapped in an anchor or not.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smittles/GsKg6/

What am I doing wrong that prevents the vertical-align property from rendering the text out centered vertically, in the same way the header does in this example.

Comment: Your h2 tag's vertical alignment is set by its line-height value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `display: table-cell` or even `float` anywere in this example.

To vertically center the text in the header, set the **line-height** of the `<h2>` to match the height of `#h2wrap`. Or remove **height** from `#h2wrap` and increase its top and bottom **padding** instead.

To vertically center the images, labels and the buttons within the `<a>` tags, set their **display** to **inline-block** and add a `vertical-align: middle`. You will have to explicitly set their widths and also [eliminate the extra spaces caused by inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), but I believe this would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple lines of text `line-height` will not work.

See [this](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) for the ways of applying vertical align. The `line-height` won't work with text that needs to wrap (which I believe you have). You'll have to use `display: table-cell`.